# How to get links from a webpage in php

Tags: php

I have the following list of links.

```
<tr><td><a href="javascript:d(43755)"> Microsoft office 2010 professional plus </a></td><td> 2012-04-09 </td><td align="right"> 28% </td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:d(43742)"> Microsoft Office 2010 all versions </a></td><td> 2010-11-03 </td><td align="right"> 63% </td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:d(43747)"> Microsoft Office 2010 Home and student </a></td><td> 2012-05-10 </td><td align="right"> 51% </td></tr>
```

Is there a way to get all numbers in the links javascript:d(number) in an array and dates in another array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = '<tr>...........YOU PAGE HERE';
$result = array(); // your result array
preg_match_all('/d\((\d+)\).*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $input, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$numbers = $result[1]; // your numbers
$dates = $reult[2]; // your dates
```

Comment: if you want to GET contents for a specific page (to then extract the info) -->

$input = file_get_contents('http://www.google.de');

Comment: it'll be more easy when fopen-url-wrappers are allowed instead of fireing up curl.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a DOM parser. If you are familiar with CuRL, this can be done in very little code. You can parse through the page and look for all the links and scrape any information you need from them.

Here is an excellent guide for CuRL: [curl tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this little library [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)